# Access shared resources as specific user

Tags: windows-7, networking, shared-folders

I have a machine in my network with shared resources. Whenever I enter that machine via IP address (192.168.x.x) I do so under a Guest account. I know the user and password that is Administrator, but I don't know how to login as that user.

I don't want to do **anything** on the remote computer to solve this issue.

I tried **net use** but I'm not sure how it works.

I remember that with some configuration, when I entered the remote machine I was welcomed with a dialog that prompts me to enter my user name / password. I guess that dialogs shows when Guest account is disabled. But how to make that dialog appear when Guest account is enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either map this share as a drive (`Computer` - rigth click - `Map network drive`, check `Use different credentials`) or try `net use l: \\192.168.x.x\share /user:xxxxx`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to specify a password with that net use command?

Comment: `net use l: \\192.168.x.x\share super_secret_pa$$w0rd /user:xxxxx`